# Set style of a specific element of a UserControl by name

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

If I have a `UserControl` with the following two `Label`s inside of it's grid like so:

```
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
    <Label x:Name="labelTitle"/>
    <Label x:Name="labelValue"/>
</Grid>
```

Can I set their styles separately from within a `ResourceDictionary` something like:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MyControl}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="MyControl.mainGrid.labelTitle">
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="MyControl.mainGrid.labelValue">
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

If possible I would like to do all of this in the `ResourceDictionary` and not have to touch the `UserControl` at all.

Comment: I think you want to go about it the other way around, make two separate styles and point the labels to the styles

Comment: @GordonAllocman I know I could do that but if possible I would like to not have to touch the `UserControl` code

Comment: Right but AFAIK styles are built to be able to target certain instantiated controls, only types of controls. If you want two controls of the same type to be styled differently you have to do it in the control not the style. They likely decided on doing it this way because externally defined styles are meant to potentially be used across multiple different controls/applications. To give a source here is the [Style Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style(v=vs.110).aspx) from MSDN and there appears to be no functionality implemented to do what you want to do

Comment: I can't definitively say no one has come up with some wonky workaround for this, but an important question is why do you want to go against the standard instead of just changing your control?

Comment: @GordonAllocman Because I do not have access to work on the control, my job is to do this in the ResourceDictionary only so we can develop the two things seperatley and easily change different themes out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using a trigger in the style based on the name.

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication34.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication34"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Name" Value="labelTitle">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="This is the Title" />
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"  Value="Left" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="Name" Value="labelValue">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="This is the Value" />
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"  Value="Right" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

MyControl.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication34.MyControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication34"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
        <Label x:Name="labelTitle" />
        <Label x:Name="labelValue" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication34.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication34"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <local:MyControl />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Screenshot:

[image]